# Is it possible to convert any mp4 file to hdri format to use in blender background

Tags: animation

I am using blender 2.8 to animate drones effect. 
In shading mode i am trying to add background to drones using hdri files ,but hdri files are limited in internet ,i want to use my own video shooted from camera .

How to achieve this, attaching screenshot of the blender process which i am following.

[image]

Comment: No I don't you might be able to do it with an image sequence.

Comment: Any online tool to convert image sequence to hdri.?

Comment: You can use simple picture or video files as sphere panorama background, you don't need to convert it to hdri. Just add them as Environment Texture.